# Turn page with UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider, ebook-reader

I am  working on book reader app in which i want to Turn pages using UISlider

I have tried following code in viewdidload:

```
    pageSlider =[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 350, 250, 15)];
    [self.pageSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(turnPageWithSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.pageSlider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.pageSlider.maximumValue = [self numberOfPagesInLeavesView:self->leavesView];
    self.pageSlider.value = self->leavesView.currentPageIndex;
    [self.view addSubview:pageSlider];
```

and the method:

```
(void)turnPageWithSlider:(id)sender
{
  objScaner.keyword = nil;
  [leavesView reloadData];
  int pageIndex = (int) [self.pageSlider value];
  [self.pageSlider setValue:(float)pageIndex];
  self->leavesView.currentPageIndex = pageIndex;

 [self displayPageNumber:pageIndex + 1];
}
```

but here `turnPageWithSlider:` method is not called
slider is appearing but not working properly

thanks.....

Comment: try to change pageslider with self.pageslider in first and last line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace pageslider with `self.pageslider` in the first line where you are initialising and also when you adding subview.